# pass selected dropdownlist value to where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, parameters

I am inserting into a table by using the newxt query, but I dont know what the syntax is for telling the query I need to insert where training_id = &dateSelected& , the query below works by using a static value to test (2) .

Please help.

```
private void InsertInfo()
    {
        var dateSelected = dpDate.SelectedItem.Value;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

    string sql =    "INSERT INTO personTraining (name,training_id, training,trainingDate,trainingHour, trainingSession)SELECT @Val1,training_id,training,trainingDate,trainingHour,trainingSession FROM tbl_training WHERE  training_id = 2";
```

Comment: If you extend your code to show how the SQL statement is executed, and also how @Val1 is used, we can provide more specific examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parameters as follows:

```
private void InsertInfo()
{
  var dateSelected = dpDate.SelectedItem.Value;
  using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
  {
       conn.Open();
       SqlCommand command= conn.CreateCommand();
       command.CommandText=     "INSERT INTO personTraining (name,training_id, training,trainingDate,trainingHour, trainingSession)SELECT @Val1,training_id,training,trainingDate,trainingHour,trainingSession FROM tbl_training WHERE  training_id = @trainingID";

      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trainingID",dateSelected);
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

However, you have another `@Val1` parameter in your query; I don't know where is that coming from.

Comment: thanks it think i got it, so we cannot use anymore the '&' simbols in .net?

Comment: @user959443: you can use them in VB.NET to concatenate strings but that's a terrible practice when it comes to building SQL queries. Don't *ever* do that because you'll be exposing yourself to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example.  I don't know how you are executing your `string sql` so I will use a `SqlCommand`-based example.

SQL:

```
INSERT INTO personTraining 
(name,training_id, training,trainingDate,trainingHour, trainingSession)
SELECT @Val1,training_id,training,trainingDate,trainingHour,trainingSession
FROM tbl_training 
WHERE training_id = @training_id;
```

C#:

```
SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("training_id", dateSelected);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another Parameter object to the SqlCommand object, and set the value of the Parameter to the dateSelected.

Comment: Hi I need to pass the selected id for the where clause not the value, how would I do this? <asp:DropDownList ID="dpDate" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                        DataTextField="trainingDate" DataValueField="training_id" 
                        AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select Date</asp:ListItem>
                   
                    </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: You can put parameters anywhere.